# Display image between dates once admin has granted approval

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Everything displays fine when there is a single Yes approval.  (a yes/yes approval is not possible due to code in admin area).

If there are two dates with a Yes/No combination on the same date range the number of rows = 0 and therefore displays "FILLER IMAGE". I wish for only the YES approval to display and disregard the NO.

What I think i need to do is great and array of ids after checking the database of matching dates and then query the array for Yes approvals.

I could be wrong but if that is correct how is best to implement.

Thanks

```
     <?php 



include('mysql_connect.php');{

  $location='1';

  }
  {
 $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM advert WHERE adloc = '$location'");


if($resultSet->num_rows > 0){
    while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $id = $rows ['id'];
        $start = $rows ['start'];
        $end = $rows ['enddate'];
        $business = $rows ['business'];
        $email = $rows ['email'];
        $tel = $rows ['tel'];
        $web = $rows ['web'];
        $advert = $rows ['image'];

    $Date = date('Y-m-d');
    $Date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date));; 
    $DateBegin = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$start"));
    $DateEnd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$end"));
}
}
if (($Date > $DateBegin) && ($Date < $DateEnd))
    {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM advert WHERE id = $id AND approval = 'Y'";
$sth = $mysqli->query($sql);



if($sth->num_rows == 0){echo "FILLER IMAGE";
}
else
{

$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
$output= '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';

    }
    }
}
?>

<?php 
echo "$output";
?>
```

Comment: you can use BETWEEN condition in a CASE clause in you sql query !

Comment: Could you edit your question so that users can understand your issue.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, to query out all the adverts that has the approval status of 'Y' between two specified dates?

Comment: Yes @Nouphal.M. There should only be one advert to display as Y as it is not possible to approve more than one advert.

Comment: Try SELECT * FROM advert WHERE (NOW() BETWEEN start AND enddate)  AND approval = 'Y'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are wrong, because you taking the last id fetched from your while

You can filtering date between and approved from you sql query directly like that

Using [BETWEEN()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html) operator and [CASE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

```
SELECT 
  (CASE WHEN 
    approval = 'Y' and 
    (NOW() BETWEEN start AND enddate)
       THEN 1 ELSE 0
  ) as approved, *
FROM advert
WHERE 
   adloc = '$location'
LIMIT 1
```

If you need only one result, distingished from others approval != 'Y'

then just

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM advert
WHERE 
   adloc = '$location' AND
   (NOW() BETWEEN start AND enddate) AND
   approval = 'Y'
LIMIT 1
```

This will return an alias field containing 1 when approval is Y and between the date range, Or 0 if not for others records

Now your code, will just containing one query

```
$query = "query ";
$smt = $mysqli->query($query);
if($smt->num_rows > 0)
{
    $result=mysqli_fetch_array($smt);
    $output= '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($result['image']).'"/>';
}else
    // not results
```

Comment: Thanks @MTroy. Totally unfamiliar with this technique. Just trying to get my head around it. Where should this be used in my code? I see there are no variables for the start and end?

Comment: you have not need to make more than one query, then just test if num rows > 0 and getting the image, else your other action (looking for updated code)

Comment: oh sry, doesn't see you only want one result, then i updating my code

Comment: Thanks @MTroy just trying now.

Comment: Perfect thank you! Had a quick change on the $result to $rows but i'm sure you would have known that if you had seen it!!! @MTroy

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: @Strawberry, you're right, but order by what ? enddate ?

Comment: Well, the implied order is `id` (because it's presumably indexed), so that's one idea.

Comment: yes id, if presumably indexed, or combined id and enddate if not ? <off> what is the syntax to highlight in comment ?</off> (ok i've **`found`** :)